# xcode ios - image in tableview section header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

This is my code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,60,60);

    if (section == 0){
        return 0;
    }else if (section == 1){
        return 0;
    }else if (section == 2){
        return 0;
    }else if (section == 3){
        return 0;
    }else if (section == 5){
        return imageView;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So the image appears but the problem is that the `imageView.frame` is not working, the photo size is appearing equal to the header height, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you implement the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method you must also implement the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method to return the desired header height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 5) {
        return 70;
    } else {
        return 0;
}
```

And your `viewForHeaderInSection` method could be make better:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 5) {
        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 60);
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70)];
        [view addSubview:imageView];

        return view;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, works fine. can I add a background behind the image ??

Comment: You can add anything you want to the view.